# В продолжение вопроса о "право-лево"

Tags: этимология

Десна — значит "правый", так? Тогда почему мягкие ткани вокруг зубов называют деснами? При чем тут правая сторона?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Правый" все-таки не *десна*, а скорее *десный*. Будем рассматривать слово *десница*.

**ДЕСНА** «мышечная ткань, покрывающая корни зубов». Общеслав. Праслав. *dęsna <* dentsna «десна», должно быть, связано с и.-е. названием зуба *dent. Ср. лат. dens, dentis «зуб», от него франц. dentiste «зубной врач», которое, будучи заимствованным, стало звучать в рус. яз.* дантист *«зубной врач, техник» (франц. en читается как а). Праслав.* dentsna «десна» образовано с суф.прил. *-sn-a от* dent «зуб». Впоследствии *dentsna изменилось в* dęsna в связи с упрощением tsn > sn и образованием носового ę из en. В вост.-слав. диал. условиях ę дал е, вместо ожидаемого ['а] (графич. я). Ср. др.-рус. дясна «десна», где я закономерно из ę.

Что касается происхождения слова **ДЕСНИЦА**, то "правая рука", также *десн**а**я*, церк., ср. ст.-слав. *деснъ* δεξιός. Родственно лит. dešinas "правый", нареч. dešinai "ловко; направо", dešinŷs, dešine "правая рука", др.-инд. dáksinas "дельный, ловкий, правый, южный", греч. δεξιός, лат. dexter, ирл. dess "правый, южный", алб. djathtё. Далее, сюда же, вероятно, греч. δέχομαι "принимаю", лат. decet "подобает".